# Is there a function that defines the trace of a matrix A divided by its determinant?

Tags: matrices

Given an $n \times n$ invertible matrix $A$, does there exist a function $f(n,A)$ in any field of mathematics such that:
$$
                            f(n,A) = \dfrac{\mbox{tr}(A)}{\det(A)}
$$
If so, has its behavior been studied in any depth? Also is there a connection between eigenvalues defining the trace and determinant of A and additive number theory?

Comment: What is interesting about it?

Comment: You just defined this function, so it certainly exists... Another way to describe it is that it is the sum of the eigenvalues divided by the product of the eigenvalues. What do you want to know about its behavior?

Comment: @LukasGeyer: why would it be so? Eigenvalues of a matrix needn't be the diagonal entries unless it's triangular.

Comment: The trace is always the sum of the eigenvalues (listed by algebraic multiplicity) and the determinant is always the product of the eigenvalues (listed by algebraic multiplicity).  See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when $A$ is a 2 by 2 matrix then we can define a 4 by 4 matrix $A'$ which is an operator on the 4 dimensional vector space of 2 by 2 matrices. The operator $A'$ is defined by the equation

$$A'(M)=(A')^{-1}MA$$

where $M$ is an arbitrary 2 by 2 matrix. Then it is the case that

$$Tr(A')=Tr(A)/ \det(A)$$

I just figured this out this morning while doing part (a) of #6 on the August 2012 University of Maryland algebra qualifying exam. If you are interested in how this fact is applied to character theory / representation theory of finite groups you should read the full problem, it's a really neat question!

I don't know of any relation to additive number theory.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Interesting observation. Please format with mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference